# How to generate XML from Camel route

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I am new to the apache camel with xslt. Using camel with Spring boot. 
Please help me to generate xml using XSLT.

Expected result is :

```
 <employees>
   <empoyee>
     <name>emp1</name>
     <id>1</id>
   </empoyee>
   <empoyee>
     <name>emp2</name>
     <id>2</id>
   </empoyee>
    ........
 </employees>
```

I am getting the from DB using datasource using select query. Query returns many records.

```
  from("quartz2://timer?cron={{cron.schedule}}")
        .autoStartup(true)
        .routeId("RouteId")
        .log("Route enabled")
        .setBody(constant("select name, id from Employee"))
        .to("jdbc:dataSource?resetAutoCommit=false")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"Emp name : ${body[0]['name']}")
        .marshal(xStreamDataFormat)
        .to("xslt:sample.xslt")
```

How can I get the array Object in XSLT and how to iterate in XSLT?

Comment: Hi! Is the question about how you process the records in XSLT, or how you split them and process them once the XSLT is complete? It would help if you show some kind of example of what your XML is before and after the XSLT step.

Comment: @Screwtape, How to process the records in XLST, dont want to split. already provided sample expected xml above. Fetching the records from the DataBase and generate single xml from it?

Comment: So you want to convert SQL result to XML, right?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli, Yes. I want to convert SQL result to XML using spring-boot and Camel

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Oracle, I am able to get data from datasource in array of obects.